# Update woocommerce products price with MySQL by multiplying price with other meta value

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am using ACF in wordpress.
I added new custom field to woocommerce products called "cust_cur" (number field).

I need to multiply this cust_cur with 0.51 and get the results to the products price fields where i have manually added values to the cust_cur.
https://prnt.sc/qwmokq

Table 'wp_postmeta' structure:

```
meta_id Primary bigint(20)
post_id Index bigint(20)
meta_key Index varchar(255) 
meta_value longtext
```

---

So, something like this but i don't understand how to link the value with two columns:
meta_key and meta_value:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta m 
    JOIN wp_posts p ON m.post_id=p.id 
    AND m.meta_key = '_price' 
    AND m.meta_key = 'cust_cur' 
    AND p.post_type = 'product'
SET m.meta_value = m.meta_value*0.51 WHERE m.meta_key = 'cust_cur' AND m.meta_value IS NOT NULL
```

The last sentence is where i dont know how to join them.

**SET m.meta_value** (the "_price" value) **= m.meta_value** (the "cust_cur" value) ***0.51 WHERE m.meta_key = 'cust_cur' AND m.meta_value** (the "cust_cur" value) **IS NOT NULL**

Any ideas how to complete this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a valid query if the tables and columns fit, your last question was closed, because without knowing table structure, nobody can help you at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update woocommerce price by multiplying it with meta \_length value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028479/update-woocommerce-price-by-multiplying-it-with-meta-length-value-in-mysql)

Comment: if any one is familiar with woocommerce and wordpress they know the table structure: The last sentence which i said is wrong is this part: meta_value(_length)*0.51 WHERE meta_value(_length) IS NOT NULL

Comment: I dont know how to refer to the meta value "length" in woocommerce.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by length and i don't know the datatype of meta_value . Like i said, this is why your questions are closed.

Comment: I updated the whole post and made changes to better understand what i am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully it's more clear now and readable.

Comment: I think your query is still guud. i am not sure if you shouldn't cast your meat_value as Integer or double. So your Query say now. Get me all the wp_postmeta row, with are also in wp_posts with criteria. Then search all these rows and update all that are not NULL and m.meta_key = 'cust_cur'. so check with a select if wtha ll the critereria you have all rows and the run your update in phpmayadmin with the multiplicator 1.0, so that nothing is changed of your criteria need so refining

Comment: Thanks for reply. I run the query with * 1, Result was with no rows affected. Query itself ran fine. So the last sentence where i commented SET m.meta_value (to where???) ... i think this is the problem because mysql cant understand where to set the meta_value because there are many meta_name 's . I need to associate meta_name with meta_value to update the _price column somehow, something like ... set the meta_value where meta_name = '_price' which = m.meta_value (the "cust_cur" value) *0.51 WHERE m.meta_key = 'cust_cur' AND m.meta_value (the "cust_cur" value) IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Rum SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta m  WHERE m.meta_key = 'cust_cur' AND m.meta_value IS NOT NULL and see where it gets you. After that runs ok inner JOIN wp_posts p ON m.post_id=p.id when that runs ok andd then next and and so on till you got all the rows you need.